# How to add markup to an XML text using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a mark-up text in XML format. I need to add markup, namely to add tags to certain words if they occur in the text.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = '''<root><par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words one and two</par></root>'''

profs=['one','two']
tag='<key>'
tag_cl='</key>'

root = ET.fromstring(doc)
for child in root:
    for word in profs:
        if word in child.text:
            child.text=child.text.replace(word, f'{tag}{word}{tag_cl}')
    print(child.text)
```

If there are no nested tags in the text, this works. If there is a tag (in this example 'fr'), then child.text is regarded only as the text that precedes the first tag. Surely there must be some simple solution to perform the task I described. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for the task.

Comment: _"then child.text is regarded only as the text that precedes the first tag"_ -- no, the content of `<par>` is: (1) a text node, (2) an `<fr>` node, and (3) another text node.  You would need to handle this in your code, and would need to know which specific text nodes need to be grouped based on their enclosing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search the tail element. You can duplicate the if condition for elem.text if necessary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = '''<root><par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words one and two</par></root>'''

profs=['one','two']
tag= ET.Element('key')

root = ET.fromstring(doc)

for elem in root.iter():
    #print(elem.text)
    #print(elem.tail)
    for word in profs:
        if elem.tail != None and word in elem.tail:
            tag.text=word
            elem.tail = elem.tail.replace(word, ET.tostring(tag).decode())
      
    if elem.tail != None:
        print(elem.tail)
```

Output:

```
text with key words <key>one</key> and <key>two</key>
```

**Option 2:**
If you would like real element etree objects instead of html tags you can do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import html
doc = '''<root><par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words one and two</par></root>'''

profs=['one','two']
tag= ET.Element('key')

root = ET.fromstring(doc)

for elem in root.iter('par'):
    text_str = ET.tostring(elem).decode()
    root.remove(elem)
    for word in profs:
        tag.text=word
        text_str = text_str.replace(word, ET.tostring(tag).decode())

    par=html.unescape(ET.fromstring(text_str))

root.append(par)   
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root><par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words <key>one</key> and <key>two</key></par></root>
```

Comment: You haven't actually created any `key` elements though. If you `ET.dump(root)` you get `<root><par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words &lt;key&gt;one&lt;/key&gt; and &lt;key&gt;two&lt;/key&gt;</par></root>`

Comment: @Daniel Haley, Correct, it’s embedded html tags, in the tail text. I understood, this is what he searched for.

Comment: Added Option2 for element tree objects, too.

Comment: Not sure the html.unescape is needed, but +1 for both options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is XSLT 2.0 implementation for the task.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <par>An <fr>example</fr> text with key words one and two</par>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
            <xsl:call-template name="OneTwoSequence"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="OneTwoSequence">
            <xsl:param name="string" select="string(.)"/>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="one|two">
                  <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <key>
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </key>
                  </xsl:matching-substring>
                  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <par>An 
    <fr>example</fr> text with key words 
    <key>one</key> and 
    <key>two</key>
  </par>
</root>
```

Comment: How do you process this, python package? Thanks!

Comment: You can check Saxonica: https://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, but you'll have to use lxml instead of ElementTree to get there:

```
from lxml import html as lh
root = lh.fromstring(doc)

#locate relevant the element
target = root.xpath('//fr')[0]

#convert the relevant element to string and copy it to a new string
#that is a necessary step because we're going to have to delete the
#original string
target_str = lh.tostring(target).decode()

#make the necessary changes to the string
profs=['one','two']
for word in profs:
    if word in target_str:
        target_str = target_str.replace(word, f'<key>{word}</key>')    

#locate the destination for the new element
destination = root.xpath('//par')[0]
#remove the original target
destination.remove(target)
#insert the new string, converted into a new element
destination.insert(0,lh.fromstring(target_str))
print(lh.tostring(root))
```

The output should be your expected output.